# Share signature constraints across functions

Tags: signature, raku

Given a simple program to convert to/from bases:

```
#!perl6

my @alphabet = ('0' .. '9', 'A' .. 'Z', 'a' .. 'z').flat;
sub to-digits(Int $n is copy, Int $b where 2 <= * <= 62 --> Str) {
  my @digits; 
  while $n > 0 {
    @digits.push(@alphabet[$n % $b]);
    $n = $n div $b;
  }

  @digits.reverse.join;
}

sub from-digits(Str $digits, Int $b where 2 <= * <= 62 --> Int) {
  my $n = 0;
  for $digits.comb -> $d {
    $n = $b * $n + @alphabet.first({ $_ eq $d }, :k);
  }

  $n;
}

sub to-base(
  Str $n, 
  Int $b where 2 <= * <= 62, 
  Int $c where 2 <= * <= 62 --> Str) {
  to-digits(from-digits($n, $b), $c);
}
```

I find that I repeat my constraint on the supplied base, `where * >= 2 && * <= 62`, four times throughout my program. Looking at the documentation for [`Signatures`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#Type_Constraints) I see that you can save out a signature like so:

```
my $sig = :(Int $a where $a >= 2 && $a <= 62);
```

Is there a way that this Signature can be applied to multiple functions and/or how can I share this constraint across functions?

Comment: `sub to-digits(Int:D $n, Int:D $b where 2..62 --> Str:D) {[R~] @alphabet[$n.polymod: $b xx *]}`

Comment: @BradGilbert okay, that solution is really cool. Much more elegant than looping.

Comment: @BradGilbert What does the `:D` signify?

Comment: `:D` is a type smiley that means defined, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type#Perl_6

Answer (score 6):

It turns out that *no*, you cannot share signatures across multiple functions as outlined by @moritz in this answer: [Can I use a standalone Signature as a signature in Perl 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531393/can-i-use-a-standalone-signature-as-a-signature-in-perl-6)

However, you *can* share constraints by using a [`Subset`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#subset) as @zoffix outlined in the #perl6 Freenode irc:

```
subset Base of Int where 2 <= * <= 62;
sub to-digits(Int $n is copy, Base $b) {
  ...
}
...
```